# XSL getting value of immediately preceding element/@attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-3.0

I have an XML text file, divided into `<deposition>`s, each marked up with `<footnote>` and `<appnote>`containing identifying numbers and letters for footnote purposes. Now I want to cycle through those (XSL 3.0/Saxon) and then get an attribute of the element **immediately preceding it** to populate a new footnote 'block' called `<footnotes>` at the end of each `<deposition>` . Test can be found here http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/948Fn5a/16

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<corpus>
<deposition>
    <deposition-title>Praesent vitae</deposition-title>
    <text>
        <seg n="seg1" type="not_foo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
            adipiscing elit. Vivamus<note2 n="abc">another note 2</note2><appnote>a</appnote> ultrices consequat facilisis. 
            Suspendisse a odio<note n="def">foo note</note><footnote>1</footnote> in lobortis. Aenean 
            non dui scelerisque, rutrum est at, cursus sem.</seg>
        <seg n="seg2" type="foo">Ut pharetra bibendum ipsum, portitor 
            velit pharetra quis. Aeneano<note n="ghi">foo note</note><footnote>2</footnote> purus. Praesent 
            aliquam viverra tellus<note n="jkl">another note</note><footnote>3</footnote> in condimentum.</seg><footnote>4</footnote>
    </text>
</deposition>
<deposition>
    <deposition-title>Elementum arcu non</deposition-title>
    <text>
        <seg n="seg1" type="foo">Curabitur pulvinar leo eget. Orci varius 
            natoque penatibus et magnis dis<note n="mno">foo note</note><footnote>1</footnote> montes, 
            nascetur ridiculus mus.</seg><footnote>2</footnote>
        <seg n="seg2" type="foo">Curabitur pulvinar leo eget. Orci varius 
            natoque penatibus<note2  n="pqr">another note 2</note2><appnote>a</appnote> et 
            magnis dis<note n="stu">foo note</note><footnote>3</footnote> montes, 
            nascetur ridiculus mus.</seg><footnote>4</footnote>
        <seg n="seg3" type="not_foo">Morbi vehicula dolor bibendum enim mollis lobortis. 
            Nulla rutrum vel diam vel posuere. Aliquam pellentesque 
            malesuada elit sed tempor.</seg>
    </text>
</deposition>
<deposition>
    <deposition-title>Elementum arcu non</deposition-title>
    <text>
        <seg n="seg1" type="foo">Curabitur pulvinar leo eget. Orci varius 
            natoque penatibus et magnis dis<note n="vwx">foo note</note><footnote>1</footnote> montes, 
            nascetur ridiculus mus.</seg><footnote>2</footnote>
        <seg n="seg2" type="not_foo">Morbi vehicula dolor bibendum enim mollis lobortis. 
            Nulla rutrum vel diam vel posuere. Aliquam<note2  n="yz">another note 2</note2><appnote>a</appnote> pellentesque 
            malesuada elit sed tempor.</seg>
    </text>
</deposition>
</corpus>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="3.0">

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="deposition">
  <deposition>
    <xsl:apply-templates/> 
    <footnotes>
        <xsl:for-each select="text//footnote">
            <xsl:variable name="pos" select="./current() - 1"/>
            <footitem>
                <xsl:value-of select=". || '='"/><xsl:value-of select="preceding::node()[$pos]/@n"/>
            </footitem>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="text//appnote">
            <xsl:variable name="pos" select="./current() - 1"/>
            <appitem>
                <xsl:value-of select=". || '='"/><xsl:value-of select="preceding::node()[$pos]/@n"/>
            </appitem>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </footnotes>
  </deposition>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However the result is unexpected, likely due to misunderstanding `current()` and `preceding::node`.

For example, for the first `<deposition>` I would expect the following to appear after the last `seg` in each `deposition`:

```
<footnotes>
  <footitem>1=def</footitem>
  <footitem>2=ghi</footitem>
  <footitem>3=jkl</footitem>
  <footitem>4=seg1</footitem>
</footnotes>
<appnotes>
  <appitem>a=abc</appitem>
</appnotes>
```

But I am getting `Error executing XSLT ....cannot convert string "a" to double`.

(NB: this example is generic and the previous element could be one of many names, so hardcoding the name of an element is not a feasible solution.)

Many, many thanks in advance for all the help with this massive project!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you simply want

```
        <xsl:for-each select="text//footnote">
            <footitem>
                <xsl:value-of select=". || '='"/><xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::*[1]/@n"/>
            </footitem>
        </xsl:for-each>
         <xsl:for-each select="text//appnote">
            <appitem>
                <xsl:value-of select=". || '='"/><xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::*[1]/@n"/>
            </appitem>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

although that gives (http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/948Fn5a/17)

```
<footnotes><footitem>1=def</footitem><footitem>2=ghi</footitem><footitem>3=jkl</footitem><footitem>4=seg2</footitem><appitem>a=abc</appitem></footnotes></deposition>
```

so `4=seg2` and not `4=seg1`.

And you don't really need two adjacent `value-of`s, you can use e.g.

```
<xsl:value-of select="., preceding-sibling::*[1]/@n" separator="="/>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/948Fn5a/18 or

```
                <xsl:value-of select=". || '=' || preceding-sibling::*[1]/@n"/>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/948Fn5a/19

Comment: Martin, that's perfect (despite my typo on `4=seg1`). Thanks very much for patiently providing me solutions the last few days. I've learned a lot.