# Controlling processing order for correct updating of values

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Using a large XML corpus, I am integrating two sets of XSL 3.0 code for building footnotes found at 
[XSL numbering using two different sets simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48123059/xsl-numbering-using-two-different-sets-simultaneously) (creates numbers) and at [XSL getting value of immediately preceding element/@attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48132710/xsl-getting-value-of-immediately-preceding-element-attribute) (creates notes) .

The combined code is found here: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/948Fn5a/24

Below is the XML and XSL 3.0 found on the xsltfiddle linked above, processed by Saxon. I will post the problem immediately:

With the XSL `<xsl:value-of select=". || '=' || preceding-sibling::*[1]/@n"/>` one expects the number or letter in the `appnote` / `footnote` to be returned in the block `footnotes`. The contents of `preceding-sibling` are being returned correctly, so evidently the XPATH is targeting  the correct element(s).

Is this an issue of order of processing within XSL?  That somehow the `footnote` is created, then `footnote-block` created, and finally `footnote` receives its respective number/letter? Does this require another `mode`?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<corpus>
  <deposition>
    <deposition-title>Praesent vitae</deposition-title>
    <text>
        <seg n="seg1" type="not_foo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
            adipiscing elit. Vivamus<note2 n="abc">another note 2</note2> ultrices consequat facilisis. 
            Suspendisse a odio<note n="def">foo note</note> in lobortis. Aenean 
            non dui scelerisque, rutrum est at, cursus sem.</seg>
        <seg n="seg2" type="foo">Ut pharetra bibendum ipsum, portitor 
            velit pharetra quis. Aeneano<note n="ghi">foo note</note> purus. Praesent 
            aliquam viverra tellus<note n="jkl">another note</note> in condimentum.</seg>
    </text>
  </deposition>
  <deposition>
    <deposition-title>Elementum arcu non</deposition-title>
    <text>
        <seg n="seg1" type="foo">Curabitur pulvinar leo eget. Orci varius 
            natoque penatibus et magnis dis<note n="mno">foo note</note> montes, 
            nascetur ridiculus mus.</seg>
        <seg n="seg2" type="foo">Curabitur pulvinar leo eget. Orci varius 
            natoque penatibus<note2  n="pqr">another note 2</note2> et 
            magnis dis<note n="stu">foo note</note> montes, 
            nascetur ridiculus mus.</seg>
        <seg n="seg3" type="not_foo">Morbi vehicula dolor bibendum enim mollis lobortis. 
            Nulla rutrum vel diam vel posuere. Aliquam pellentesque 
            malesuada elit sed tempor.</seg>
    </text>
  </deposition>
  <deposition>
    <deposition-title>Elementum arcu non</deposition-title>
    <text>
        <seg n="seg1" type="foo">Curabitur pulvinar leo eget. Orci varius 
            natoque penatibus et magnis dis<note n="vwx">foo note</note> montes, 
            nascetur ridiculus mus.</seg>
        <seg n="seg2" type="not_foo">Morbi vehicula dolor bibendum enim mollis lobortis. 
            Nulla rutrum vel diam vel posuere. Aliquam<note2  n="yz">another note 2</note2> pellentesque 
            malesuada elit sed tempor.</seg>
    </text>
  </deposition>
  </corpus>
```

XSL which adds footnote numbers and then creates a 'block' of notes at bottom of `deposition`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="3.0">

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<!-- ADD FOOTNOTE NUMBERING, IN TWO DIFFERENT SETS: 1, 2, 3... and a, b, c... -->
<xsl:mode name="add-notes" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:variable name="notes">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="add-notes"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="seg[@type = 'foo'] | note" mode="add-notes">
  <xsl:next-match/>
  <footnote/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="note2" mode="add-notes">
  <xsl:next-match/>
  <appnote/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$notes/node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="footnote">
  <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:number level="any" format="1" from="deposition"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="appnote">
  <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:number level="any" format="a" from="deposition"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- CREATE FOOTNOTE BLOCK FROM NUMBERING ABOVE -->
<xsl:template match="deposition">
  <deposition>
    <xsl:apply-templates/> 
    <footnote-block>
        <xsl:for-each select="text//footnote">
            <footitem>
                <xsl:value-of select=". || '=' || preceding-sibling::*[1]/@n"/>
            </footitem>
        </xsl:for-each>
         <xsl:for-each select="text//appnote">
            <appitem>
                <xsl:value-of select=". || '=' || preceding-sibling::*[1]/@n"/>
            </appitem>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </footnote-block>
  </deposition>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, basically, currently you are trying to insert the number and extract it in the same processing step and that way the numbers are not found, so, to follow the same pattern as before, you would need to separate the steps with another mode:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <!-- ADD FOOTNOTE  -->
  <xsl:mode name="add-notes" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <!-- number footnotes and notes IN TWO DIFFERENT SETS: 1, 2, 3... and a, b, c... -->
  <xsl:mode name="number-notes" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:variable name="notes">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="add-notes"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="seg[@type = 'foo'] | note" mode="add-notes">
      <xsl:next-match/>
      <footnote/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="note2" mode="add-notes">
      <xsl:next-match/>
      <appnote/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:variable name="numbered-notes">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$notes/node()" mode="number-notes"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$numbered-notes/node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="footnote" mode="number-notes">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:number level="any" format="1" from="deposition"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="appnote" mode="number-notes">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:number level="any" format="a" from="deposition"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

    <!-- CREATE FOOTNOTE BLOCK FROM NUMBERING ABOVE -->
    <xsl:template match="deposition">
      <deposition>
        <xsl:apply-templates/> 
        <footnote-block>
            <xsl:for-each select="text//footnote">
                <footitem>
                    <xsl:value-of select=". || '=' || preceding-sibling::*[1]/@n"/>
                </footitem>
            </xsl:for-each>
             <xsl:for-each select="text//appnote">
                <appitem>
                    <xsl:value-of select=". || '=' || preceding-sibling::*[1]/@n"/>
                </appitem>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </footnote-block>
      </deposition>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/948Fn5a/25